# AuthSession does not redirect to url when scope query param contains refresh_token

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to launch the authentication flow using AuthSession expo module, but when the scope query param contains refresh_token, AuthSession tries to redirect to the OAuth URL, but it redirects back to auth.expo.io.

When I do not provide the scope query param, AuthSession redirects the my OAuth URL.

Does anyone have experience this issue?

```
const result = await AuthSession.startAsync({
            authUrl: (
                OAUTH_URL +
                '?response_type=token' +
                `&display=touch` +
                `&scope=web%20api%20refresh_token` + 
                `&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}` + 
                `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUrl)}`

            )
        })

        console.log(result);
        const { type, errorCode } = result;
        if (type === 'success') {
            console.log('redirect');
        } else {
            console.log('error')
            console.log(errorCode);
        }
```